# How to change Leadership from Charisma based to Intelligence based

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills

Is it possible to change the Charisma modifier to Intelligence when using [Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership---final)? I have read now over a dozen traits and feats but could not find anything.

**Background:** I want to play a Magus Marshal with a Leadership focus in the Worldwound campaign, but since the Magus is Int based I am a bit desperate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way to base the feat [Leadership](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/leadership---final) on Intelligence rather than Charisma appears to be the [wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard) archetype [instructor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo---wizard-archetypes/instructor-wizard-archetype), which seems to be written for a single-class wizard rather than a 1-level dip for a magus. Nonetheless, the instructor's extraordinary ability apprentice says, in part, that...

> Because cohorts are most interested in the instructor's magical ability, the instructor uses his Intelligence modifier, rather than Charisma, to determine his Leadership score. At 7th level, an instructor may select the Leadership feat—using his Intelligence modifier to determine his Leadership score—but doing so only provides followers, never a second cohort.

Because the extraordinary ability apprentice replaces arcane bond, the entirety of the extraordinary ability apprentice should be available with but one level in wizard, making it so that a magus 6/instructor wizard 1 can pick the feat Leadership and have the feat based on his Intelligence instead of Charisma. But, like in any such case that relies on careful reading, talk to the GM.

While many feats, traits, and even magic items add to a creature's leadership score, this is the only official Pathfinder tool that I've found that changes the ability score on which the feat Leadership is based. (There's apparently no feat like *D&D 3.5*'s Might Makes Right (*Rac* 166) for *Pathfinder*, for example.) That the change happens to switch Charisma to Intelligence is just coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

**Ask your DM**

I couldn't find any mechanical ways to change leadership from charisma to intelligence, so I would recommend speaking with your DM about making this sort of change (perhaps he would allow you to take a second feat that allows leadership to be int based). You could call it "Strategic Leader", or "Lead from Behind". SO you would take the Leadership feat, and then this new "Strategic Leader" feat. I'm sure that if you were willing to drop a feat into it, your DM would be pretty willing to work with you.

**But...**

I frankly wouldn't be surprised if your DM denied your request. The sole use of Charisma is for social interactions (which is what leadership is at the end of the day). It sounds like you want your cake and to eat it too. Have a fully capable combat character that sacrifices nothing into charisma while still getting the benefit of a character with effectively high charisma.

Answer (score 0):

The Wizard archetype Instructor is the only way to go. The wording is a bit odd but it only requires a 3 level dip, which becomes clear when compared to the consistent formatting pathfinder uses.

> Because cohorts are most interested in the instructor’s magical ability, the instructor uses his Intelligence modifier, rather than Charisma, to determine his Leadership score. At 7th level, an instructor may select the Leadership feat—using his Intelligence modifier to determine his Leadership score—but doing so only provides followers, never a second cohort.

You gain *all* the abilities from **Apprentice** at 1st level, the last bit isn't even granting you a feat (since it would say "gains leadership") that it's just clarifying that if you take leadership you don't gain a second cohort.

Cohorts use the formula of "XP awarded to player*(Cohorts level/your level)" so you would want to take those levels first so you aren't dragging around a liability for most of your campaign.

Interestingly this forces you to either spend the time (and maybe gold, but that's for your DM to decide) retraining his commoner level or always have a follower that 3 PC levels behind you.